# Rendering HTML in a data table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a data table I am rendering to a web page. I want to display a checkbox on each row. However when I try to display it is shows the html. Is there any way around this?

Class definition:

```
    public int analysisId { get; set; }
    public string heatName { get; set; }
    public DateTime analysisTime { get; set; }
    public string sampleType { get; set; }
    public string grade { get; set; }
    public string productId { get; set; }
    public string element { get; set; }
    public float value { get; set; }
```

The code in my model is below:

```
        DataTable GridData = new DataTable();
        GridData.Columns.Add("CheckBoxes");
        GridData.Columns.Add("Analysis ID");
        GridData.Columns.Add("Analysis Time");
        GridData.Columns.Add("Sample Type");
        GridData.Columns.Add("Product ID");

        foreach (var item in elementheaders)
        {
            GridData.Columns.Add(item.Trim());
        }

        int gridend = GridData.Columns.Count;
        int gridrow = 0;//x
        int listrow = 0;//z
        int checknum = 0;

foreach (int analysis in ChemList.Select(d => d.analysisId).Distinct())
{
    DataRow dr = GridData.NewRow();
    GridData.Rows.Add(dr);
    GridData.Rows[gridrow][0] = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("<input type='checkbox' id="+checknum+">");
    GridData.Rows[gridrow][1] = ChemList[listrow].analysisId;
    GridData.Rows[gridrow][2] = ChemList[listrow].analysisTime;
    GridData.Rows[gridrow][3] = ChemList[listrow].sampleType;
    GridData.Rows[gridrow][4] = ChemList[listrow].productId;
}
```

In my view:

```
<div id="grid">
    <table id="example"  class ="gridTable">
        <thead class="gridHead">
            <tr>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Columns)
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Rows)
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Display Template for cells:

```
@model TheManhattanProject.Models.CellValueViewModel

<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Value)
</td>
```

Display Template for Rows:

```
@model TheManhattanProject.Models.RowViewModel

<tr>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Values)
</tr>
```

Display Template for Columns:

```
@model TheManhattanProject.Models.ColumnViewModel

<th>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
</th>
```

I have two view models for rendering this. One for each cell and row. The row is composed of a list of cell values.

Comment: Is the code in your question from your view?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC? Is this code in your View or Controller? What is GridData? Please include more information about the problem.

Comment: GridData is part of org.eclipse.swt.layout. 01.04?

Comment: Sorry, added more code to my question. This is ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Can you please also include your model class definition?

Comment: Is GridData a DataTable? I dont think you can use DisplayFor with a DataTable. You usually work with typed lists in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Added more relevant code. I'll provide any more that you need.

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner The DisplayFor seems to be working fine with the exception of outputting the html instead of rendering it.

Comment: can you show the html that you get?

Comment: It outputs the table with the columns I specify. In the checkbox column though is displays <input type='checkbox' id=1> (id shows a different number for each row) instead of an actual checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer. It's an extension of what Matthew was trying to tell me.

```
@using System;
@model TheManhattanProject.Models.CellValueViewModel
<td>
@{if(Model.Value.StartsWith("<input type='checkbox'"))
{

    @Html.Raw(Model.Value);

}
else
{

    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Value);

}
}
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a customized display template for checknum that doesn't html encode.

Your ViewModel would use:

```
GridData.Rows[gridrow][0] = checknum;
```

The display template would use

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Int>" %>

<input type="checkbox" id="@Model" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have three display templates I'm using right now to render the grid. How would that fit into them? I'll update the question with those. I forgot to put those in earlier.